# Find with AWK and Replace

Tags: unix, awk, gsub, gawk

i have a file called sso_med.txt

```
        insert into brs.user_components (user_name, component_id, created_date, created_by, last_updated_date, last_updated_by) values ('502683504',16,current_date, '502264160', current_date, '502264160');
        insert into brs.user_components (user_name, component_id, created_date, created_by, last_updated_date, last_updated_by) values ('502689031',15,current_date, '502264160', current_date, '502264160');
        insert into brs.user_components (user_name, component_id, created_date, created_by, last_updated_date, last_updated_by) values ('502689031',16,current_date, '502264160', current_date, '502264160');
        insert into brs.user_components (user_name, component_id, created_date, created_by, last_updated_date, last_updated_by) values ('212462117', 15, current_date, '502264160', current_date, '502264160');
        insert into brs.user_components (user_name, component_id, created_date, created_by, last_updated_date, last_updated_by) values ('212462117', 16, current_date, '502264160', current_date, '502264160');
```

I want to introduce a space between `'502689031',16,current_date,`

So I tried the below command

```
awk '{gsub(/,[0-9a-zA-Z]/, ", "); print}' sso_med.txt
```

But I am not getting what I am expecting

```
insert into brs.user_components (user_name, component_id, created_date, created_by, last_updated_date, last_updated_by) values ('502683504', 6, urrent_date, '502264160', current_date, '502264160'); 
insert into brs.user_components (user_name, component_id, created_date, created_by, last_updated_date, last_updated_by) values ('502689031', 5, urrent_date, '502264160', current_date, '502264160'); 
insert into brs.user_components (user_name, component_id, created_date, created_by, last_updated_date, last_updated_by) values ('502689031', 6, urrent_date, '502264160', current_date, '502264160');
```

Comment: Its cutting out the 'c' from current_date and '1' from the number and replacing them with space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***awk*** solution:

```
awk '{ gsub(/, */, ", ", $0) }1' sso_med.txt
```

The output:

```
insert into brs.user_components (user_name, component_id, created_date, created_by, last_updated_date, last_updated_by) values ('502683504', 16, current_date, '502264160', current_date, '502264160');
insert into brs.user_components (user_name, component_id, created_date, created_by, last_updated_date, last_updated_by) values ('502689031', 15, current_date, '502264160', current_date, '502264160');
insert into brs.user_components (user_name, component_id, created_date, created_by, last_updated_date, last_updated_by) values ('502689031', 16, current_date, '502264160', current_date, '502264160');
```

---

- `gsub(/, */, ", ", $0)` - replace/***rearrange*** each separator (i.e. `,`) with a single trailing whitespace

Answer (score 0):

Just give the back reference :

```
awk '{gsub(/,[0-9a-zA-Z]/, " &"); print}' sso_med.txt
```

Comment: It introduced an extra ,